# Secure access to all file outside the web directory in Symfony 3.1

Tags: php, symfony, security, logfile

I'm currently working on a project in Symfony.
Now i have deployed the project to production.

I've noticed that if i go to **domain.com/var/logs/prod.log** than i'm able to download the file. Is there a way to protect everything outside the **Web directory** so that no matter what you type in the url you will be redirected to the web directory.
Or let me know if you have an other method to block access.

Because now i think that the project is not that secure now that i found this error.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems like a problem with the server configuration. The DocumentRoot of your project shouldn't be on the root directory of symfony, it should be on the web/ folder. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: I forgot to say that it's a subdomain. I don't know if i have deployed it correctly. I have uploaden the whole symfony inside the subdomain directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you have a subdomain you have to point it to **web** directory and don't upload all symfony files in public folder.

If your subdomain is a subfolder then you can upload symfony project somewhere and make a symbolic link from web folder and place it anywhere you like.